# express app not sending POST request to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

I'm making a CRUD api using express and trying to connect to MongoDB Atlas via mongooseJS. The problem is that whenever I try to make a get or a post request, there is no response from the server whatsoever. The server just times out.

I have created a database on MongoDB atlas and my code says that it successfully connected to the database.

Connection code:

```js
const db = require('mongoose');

db.connect(process.env.DB_QUERY, { // DB_QUERY is the connection query in .env file
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
}, () => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to Mongo DB');
});
```

Schema I'm using (stored in Item.js):

```js
const db = require('mongoose');

const ItemSchema = db.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: Number,
    category: String,
    description: String,
    ratings: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        default: 0
    }
});

module.exports = db.model('Items', ItemSchema);
```

Post and Get Routes:

```js
const express = require('express');
const Item = require('../models/Item');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const items = await Item.find();
    res.json(items);
});

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const item = new Item(req.body);
        const dbItem = await item.save();
        res.json(item);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json(error);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Update: I removed the callback function in the database connection and now it gives me an Authentication Failure. I've cross checked multiple times and the username, password and db name are correct.

I have already whitelisted 0.0.0.0/0 in the Network Access on MongoDB Atlas

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I created a new user for accessing the database and now it magically works